# Android Studio 4.2 @Generated not found

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I get this issue when trying to compile an Android project with Dagger2 while using the new Android Studio version 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using: `compileOnly 'com.github.pengrad:jdk9-deps:1.0'` for each module that uses Dagger.